# How HTML FORM take only letters not numbers?

Tags: php, html, web

In may Addvalue.php file 3 fields id, name, color… in id only numbers allow, in name and color only letter is allowed. Values successfully inserted into my database, but the problem is when user write NAME and COLOR in the HTML FORM field only LETTERS allow to write, if write any NUMBER message appears "Only letter allowed".... But it takes both Numbers and Letter. here is my both file  code:

Addvalue.php code:

```
<form  method="post" action="addh.php">
<input type="number" name="id"  id="id" required /> <span class="error">* </span> 
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" required /> <span class="error">* </span>
<input type="text" name="color" id="color" />
<?php
include("config.php");
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                 $id = $_POST["id"];
      $name = $_POST["name"];
      $color = $_POST["color"];     
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/",$name)) {
       echo "Only letters allowed"; 
     } 
 if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/",$color)) {
       echo "Only letters allowed"; 
     }
     }
?>
```

addh.php code:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
    $sql="INSERT INTO honda (id, name, color)
VALUES ('$_POST[id]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[color]')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    echo "Values Inserted";
?>
```

Comment: You can use php function ctype_alnum($string). Checks for alphanumeric character(s)

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL Injection this way. Review MySQLi Prepared Statements. Also, you can use JS to validate or force the input to be what you want before it;s posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather then using PHP, try the HTML pattern Attribute in input, like this:

```
<form action="">
Country code: <input type="text" name="country_code" 
pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" title="Three letter country code">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

For more infos:
[W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

Comment: Bad data could still get to the DB this way.

Answer (score -1):

PHP loads before the HTML and isn't available until the next load. So your page currently.

Loads this:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                 $id = $_POST["id"];
      $name = $_POST["name"];
      $color = $_POST["color"];     
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/",$name)) {
       echo "Only letters allowed"; 
     } 
 if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/",$color)) {
       echo "Only letters allowed"; 
     }
     }
?>
```

Then this

```
<form  method="post" action="addh.php">
<input type="number" name="id"  id="id" required /> <span class="error">* </span> 
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" required /> <span class="error">* </span>
<input type="text" name="color" id="color" />
```

When that form is submitted it goes directly to this...

```
<?php
include("config.php");
    $sql="INSERT INTO honda (id, name, color)
VALUES ('$_POST[id]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[color]')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    echo "Values Inserted";
?>
```

Which blindly inserts there data, no validation. What I think you want is ...

Addvalue.php

```
<form  method="post" action="addh.php">
<input type="number" name="id"  id="id" required /> <span class="error">* </span> 
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" required /> <span class="error">* </span>
<input type="text" name="color" id="color" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then addh.php becomes:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
      $id = (int)$_POST["id"];
      $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["name"]);
      $color = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["color"]);
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/",$name)) {
          $error = 'Only letters allowed'; 
      } 
      if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/", $color)) {
          $error = 'Only letters allowed'; 
     }
     if(empty($error)) {
          include("config.php");
          $sql="INSERT INTO honda (id, name, color) VALUES ('$id','$name','$color')";
          $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
          echo "Values Inserted";
     } else {
         echo $error;
     }
}
```

You should look into prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

This is a starting point for you, untested. Other things to note the `id` should be auto-incrementing.